# Make button show up outside of container using absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-position

My goal is to create a comment button that shows up next to the text on highlight and will stay sticky next to it when scrolling.

I've found that the button shows up when within the padding but not the margin. How can I position the button to show up within the margin and keep its top / left relative to its container so that it stays in the same spot relative to the text on scroll.

Here's the screenshot - you can see that the button (top right) is hidden by the margin by shows in the padding.
[image: screenshot]

```css
.grader-content-toggle {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 155px);
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}

.comment-button {
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   right: -60px;
   top: 0px;
   background: white;
   width: 45px;
   height: 45px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 4px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
   cursor: pointer;

   svg {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown us very little code, but I'm starting an answer anyway, because there's enough to see the cause of the problem.

The problem here is that you've hidden the overflow. Unfortunately we can't mix `overflow-y:scroll` with `overflow-x:visible`.

Either:

1. Increase the left padding or
2. Add an additional wrapper, so the button is outside of the element with non-visible overflow.

Answer (score 0):

set the .comment-button position property to fixed i.s.o. absolute

Comment: The problem that I run into with position fixed is that there's no way to attach it to the  text and even if I do calculate it, if the user scrolls, the button won't move. My goal is to have a user highlight text and the button show up next to it. Then if they scroll, the button would go with it.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your goal. I guess you'll have to register where the user clicks and then position the button accordingly with js.